# Interaction.Triggers datatemplate column WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a datagrid where I declared a template comlumn with a combo box.
My first idea was to fire an Interaction.Trigger on the PreparingCellForEdit, but the template column with a combo is not firing it.
I tried to put the Interaction trigger on the combo and it is not firing even the DropDown

```
<WPFCtrlD:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static Translate:Translate.About}" Width="*" Tag="ID_SAP_MAPPING"
                                           IsReadOnly="False"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <!--Visibility="{Binding IsClassSelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  
                                        Converter={StaticResource  BoolToVisibilityCollapsedInverteConverter }}"-->
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.characteristicFiltered,
                                Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"
                                       SelectedValuePath="ID_SAP_NAME"
                                                DisplayMemberPath="ID_SAP_NAME"
                                   >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDown">
                                            <WPFCtrl:EventToCommand 
                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                Command="{Binding DataContext.PreparingCellForEditCommand, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </ComboBox>
                                <!--<Label Visibility="{Binding IsClassNotSelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  
                                       Converter={StaticResource  BoolToVisibilityCollapsedInverteConverter }}"/>-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </WPFCtrlD:ExtDataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Any idea of how to fire an event for my command before the dropdown of the combo is open?

thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ComboBox that we use in WPF is from System.Windows.Controls namespace which uses the **DropDownOpened** event.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.dropdownopened(v=vs.110).aspx

If on the other hand, you're using the ComboBox present in the System.Windows.Forms namespace, it uses the **DropDown** event.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown(v=vs.110).aspx